# Env variables in Python script with Bash Operator - Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

A disclaimer: I'm just getting my hands on Airflow. Based on my research, I could use BashOperator/PythonOperator to run a Python script. As per my understanding, if I use a PythonOperator, I need to include my Python function in the same DAG file. In the version below I am using BashOperator as the function is too big to be a part of the DAG file.

I have a DAG file:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime 
import requests

# Loading Airflow Variables
PROJECT_ID = Variable.get("project")

# Default Arguments for the Dag
DEFAULT_ARGUMENTS = {
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 5, 27)
}

with DAG('sales', 
         default_args=DEFAULT_ARGUMENTS,
         user_defined_macros={"project": PROJECT_ID}) as dag:
    
    download_dataset_task = BashOperator(
            task_id="download_dataset_task",
            bash_command=f'python /opt/airflow/dags/sales.py'
    )
download_dataset_task
```

I also have the sales script where I call an API to retrieve the data. To access the API, I need to pass the login details which I currently store as Variables. Based on my research, I could import them.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from io import StringIO
from airflow.models.variable import Variable

def main():
    username = Variable.get('usr')
    password = Variable.get('pwd')
    auth = (username, password)
    currentTimeDate = datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)
    month = int(currentTimeDate.strftime('%m'))
    year = int(currentTimeDate.strftime('%Y'))
    endmonth = monthrange(year, month)
    lastdayofmonth_str = datetime(year, month, endmonth[1])
    lastdayofmonth_formatted = lastdayofmonth_str.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    try:
        url = f"https://...&year={year}&month={month}"
        resp = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            print("Connection - success!")
            
            data = resp.content.decode('utf-8')
            df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
            df['retrieved_date'] = lastdayofmonth_formatted
            print("Data loading - success!")
            df_selected['retrieved_date'] = lastdayofmonth_formatted
            df_selected.to_csv('/opt/airflow/dags/sales_2023-03.csv')
            print("Data stored - success!")
            
    except ValueError:
        print("The snapshot was not loaded")
```

The DAG runs successfully but no file is being stored. In addition, as you can see, I have a few intermediary print statements and they don't appear in the log - if I run a bit simplified version in Jupyter, the function works as expected and the file gets downloaded.

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=sales/run_id=manual__2023-06-24T10:27:07.434320+00:00/task_id=download_dataset_task/attempt=2.log
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: sales.download_dataset_task manual__2023-06-24T10:27:07.434320+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: sales.download_dataset_task manual__2023-06-24T10:27:07.434320+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): download_dataset_task> on 2023-06-24 10:27:07.434320+00:00
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 1234 to run task
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'sales', 'download_dataset_task', 'manual__2023-06-24T10:27:07.434320+00:00', '--job-id', '260', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/sales.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpk_wbdk48']
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 260: Subtask download_dataset_task
[2023-06-24, 14:10:21 UTC] {task_command.py:376} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: sales.download_dataset_task manual__2023-06-24T10:27:07.434320+00:00 [running]> on host 5bda914fef4e
[2023-06-24, 14:10:22 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1592} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=sales
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=download_dataset_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-06-24T10:27:07.434320+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=2
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-06-24T10:27:07.434320+00:00
[2023-06-24, 14:10:22 UTC] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2023-06-24, 14:10:22 UTC] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Running command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'python /opt/***/dags/sales.py']
[2023-06-24, 14:10:22 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
[2023-06-24, 14:10:27 UTC] {subprocess.py:97} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2023-06-24, 14:10:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1406} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=sales, task_id=download_dataset_task, execution_date=20230624T102707, start_date=20230624T141021, end_date=20230624T141027
[2023-06-24, 14:10:27 UTC] {local_task_job.py:164} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-06-24, 14:10:27 UTC] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the python script sales.py you only defined main but didn't call it.
add the following at the end of the file.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Second, once you'll do it the script would run but won't work in my opinion cause its not running on airflow environment but outside of it.

You should define a PythonOperator that should call this function directly and not BashOperator (in this case you don't need the first section I suggested just to understand the problem)

```
    PythonOperator(
        task_id="download_dataset_task",
        python_callable=main
)
```

Comment: Thank you, @ozs, for the response. Is it normal to have a large py function in the same DAG file or is it recommended to store the functions themselves outside of the first DAG file?

Comment: its a manner of how you like to manage your code. I usually put it outside the dag. if you put it under the dags folder then I recommend to add this script name to .airflowignore file (under dags folder), so airflow would ignore it every time its parsing files (default every 30 seconds) cause its without dags definition